# Magento shipping discount on additional products

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to add a rule that add a fixed shipping cost for the first product in cart and a half shipping cost for each additional product.

For example:

- ProductA price = 10€
- ProductB price = 15€
- Shipping cost for each product = 5€

If the shopping cart contains, total price will be:

- ProductA only --> 10€ + 5€ (product price + shipping cost)
- 2 x ProductA --> 10€ + 10€ + 5€ + 2.5€ (product prices + shipping costs)
- ProductA + ProductB --> 10€+15€ + 5€+2.5€ (product prices + shipping costs)

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot out of the box implement that shipping fee scheme.

You can however approximate it by using the *Flat Rate* method in combination with *handling fee*.

- Handling fee: 5.0
- Per item: 2.5

In `System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods` you can enable the *Flat Rate* method. (see config in attached screenshot)

This naturally mean that the first product will be 7.5 which is not what you wanted but after that you'll have your correct prices.

[image: flat rate]

Answer (score -1):

Please go to admin panel and process like following

> system->configuration

in bottom select shippiong method that is on the left side.

> sales->shipping methods->

now in the

> flat rate->type